# \includegraphics: Dots in filename

Tags: graphics, punctuation, file-lookup

`\includegraphics` cannot handle filenames that contain more than the one dot, separating the filename from the extension. Apparently it uses everything after the first dot as extension and then, of course, complains about an unknown graphics extension.

This is annoying as I very often have filenames that contain parameter values, e.g. `plot_a0.4_b0.6.pdf`.

Is there a way to teach LaTeX to interpret only the string behind the last dot as extension?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You can hide the other dots by masking them from TeX's token scanner with `{ }`, i.e.:

```
\includegraphics{{plot_a0.4_b0.6}.pdf}
```

works fine.

Note that the extension can also be dropped, then a list of default extensions is used. See the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) manual for more information.
If you want to do this, you need to double group the filename, which makes three together with the one for the arguments:

```
\includegraphics{{{plot_a0.4_b0.6}}}
```

Comment: @uenfundachtzig: I find `grffile` easier as it provides other features too (like spaces in filenames).

Comment: @MartinSchröder Definitely easier .. when it is supported by your other packages.

Comment: Does this work with any other characters which are typically bounced back? (Spaces, etcetera?)

Comment: @kando: The dots are special here because the macros looks for a file extension. But it should work with spaces as well, as they are also handles special by the underlying TeX macros. Other, normally problematic characters like underscores should work fine out of the box.

Comment: Apparently this is no longer the preferred way to do this in 2020. It can lead to problems in newer versions of LaTeX, although it can still be used if the brackets are put around the whole expression. (Before it would also work if we put for example`/dir/{name.with.dots}.pdf`, but that is no longer the case in recent versions of latex.

Comment: @Kvothe Someone reading in 2021 might arrive at this post if you do not provide extensions (`.png` or `.pdf`) in the argument and the base filename has dots (as in `trajectoryAtg=9.8`). I generally export my graphics in two extensions `.png` and `.pdf` for quick viewing in file explorer and for publication respectively. To avoid errors, declare the extensions apriorily in the preamble `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .png, .jpg}`. For more informaton, please refer Section 4.5 of [graphics package user manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphics)

Comment: I can testify that `\includegraphics{/dir/{name.with.dots}.pdf}` indeed solves the compilation error with on Debian buster (texlive 2018.20190227-2), while the curly brackets are *not necessary anymore* on Debian bullseye (texlive 2020.20210202-3). I've not yet made the reverse test (do the addition of `{...}` breaks the compilation on more recent texlive?)

Answer (score 50):

You can use package [`grffile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grffile) with option `multidot`.

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-grffilenames

Comment: Specifying options doesn't seem to be necessary; `\usepackage{grffile}` was sufficient when I tried it.

Comment: Even works for `\includepdf` from the pdfpages Package. Excellent!

Comment: `grffile` is the best. I had to drop it due to compatibility issues with another package I could not part with a couple years ago. It was so sad. I think the perpetrator was `KOMA`. For me, despite the warnings, `KOMA` works in harmony with `geometry` .. why not `grffile` too. : /

Answer (score 6):

Actually supporting such file names was part of the initial design spec for `graphicx`. The filetype is defaulted from the extension but for cases like this there is a type key so you can go `type=eps` or `type=bmp` or whatever is needed.

---

(*copying an answer from a question marked as duplicate of this one*)

For example, to tell latex it is eps type and the extension to use for the file itself and to find the bounding box, you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\includegraphics[width=5cm,type=eps,ext=.1.eps,read=.1.eps]{example}

\end{document}
```

this includes `example.1.eps`  using xelatex, or latex/dvips etc.

Comment: That doesn't work for me (at least for `type=pdf` and `type=png`): either LaTeX complains *wrongly* that it cannot find image size, or (after giving size as parameters) fails with division by zero error.

Comment: latex can't read the image size so you need to give it in the arguments or in a matching `.bb` file with a postscript style bounding box comment. I would guess you used the arguments and went height=1cm that gives div by zero as that is a _scale_ option to resize the figure so it divides the requested height by the natural size (which is still set to 0). You need to use the `bb` key or `natheight=1cm, natwidth=1cm` to set the natural height.

Comment: I have used `bb` (and `ext=.pdf`) and it didn't work -- still *"ERROR: LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in CUDA_4.0_Math_Libraries_Performance_6_14.p4-crop.pdf (no size specifed)."*.  I didn't know about the difference between `height` and **`natheight`** and that I should have used the latter.

Comment: FYI: The command was: `\includegraphics[type=pdf,ext=.pdf,bb=0 0 595 842]{CUDA_4.0_Math_Libraries_Performance_6_14.p4-crop}` and the file was `CUDA_4.0_Math_Libraries_Performance_6_14.p4-crop.pdf` (the bounding box was taken from converted to PostScript).

Comment: hmm cuda math libraries, too close to the day job:-) I think those arguments should work (if it doesn't, it's possible my former self did something wrong I may test later...)

Comment: Actually `pdflatex` says that `bb` doesn't make sense ( *"Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb` does not make sense"* ), and it doesn't help; the `natheight` and `natwidth` doesn't help either (BoudingBox is in `pt`, isn't it?) -- still *"Cannot determine size of graphic"*, and `width` + `height` result in division by 0.

Comment: bounding box comments is bp (postscript points) or I seem to remember that if you use the bb key I allowed optional units. But it shouldn't be needed anyway as (unlike classic tex and eps files) pdftex reading pdf _can_ read the included pdf to determine its natural size. Can't look now.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to automate Martin Scharrer's routine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\parsegraphicsfilename#1{%
  \begingroup
  \def\flname{}\def\flext{}%
  \def\updateflname##1{%
    \edef\flname{\ifcsnullTF\flname{}{\flname.}##1}%
  }%
  \ifinsetTF{.}{#1}{%
    \def\reserved@a##1.##2\@nil{%
      \ifinsetTF{.}{##2}{%
        \updateflname{##1}%
        \reserved@a##2\@nil
      }{%
        \updateflname{##1}%
        \ifinsetTF{,##2,}{,eps,pdf,png,jpeg,jpg,mps,}{%
          \def\flext{##2}%
        }{%
          \updateflname{##2}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
    \reserved@a#1\@nil
    \ifcsnullTF\flname{%
      \@latex@error{Filename is empty;
        \ifcsnullTF\flext{}{ extension '\flext'}}\@ehc
    }{%
      \edef\flname{\ifcsnullTF\flext{{{\flname}}}{{\flname}.\flext}}%
    }%
  }{%
    \def\flname{#1}%
  }%
  \postgroupdef\flname\endgroup
}
\robust@def*\newincludegraphics{%
  \cpt@testopt\new@includegraphics{}%
}
\def\new@includegraphics[#1]#2{%
  \parsegraphicsfilename{#2}%
  \includegraphics[#1]{\flname}%
}
\makeatother
```

Examples

```
\begin{document}
\def\result{{\tt\detokenize\expandafter{\flname}}\endgraf}
\parsegraphicsfilename{xx}
\result
\parsegraphicsfilename{xx.yy}
\result
\parsegraphicsfilename{xx.yy.pdf}
\result
\parsegraphicsfilename{xx.yy.zz.}
\result
\parsegraphicsfilename{plot_a0.4_b0.6.pdf}
\result
% The next one gives error because there is no filename:
%  \parsegraphicsfilename{.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Real-life application:

```
\newincludegraphics[scale=1.2,clip]{my..image.file.with..many.dots.ex.pdf}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: So many lines for something `\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}` does automatically...

Comment: Just an exercise for a bored student on Christmas break.

Answer (score 3):

While the question is answered for the generic case - I often have a case, where I have files with constant (unchanging), yet unstandard extensions; and where I'd like to use these files as input "as is" to `pdflatex` in a batch script context (meaning, I wouldn't want to code any parsing logic in respect to filenames, either in the Latex code, or the batch code).

For instance, the usual `\includegraphics{mydir/file01.csv_.pdf}` would fail with:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .csv_.pdf.
```

One thing that works, is as per the answer by [@DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54653/2595):

```
\includegraphics[ext=.csv_.pdf,type=pdf,read=*]{mydir/file01}
```

... but this requires me to strip the extension from the filename, so I'd have to introduce filename parsing logic somewhere.

However, what really works for me is using `\DeclareGraphicsRule{ext}{type}{read-file}{command}` (see [grfguide.pdf: Packages in the 'graphics' bundle](http://math.ucsd.edu/~jeggers/latex/grfguide.pdf)):

```
% preamble:
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.csv_.pdf}{pdf}{*}{}

% ...

\begin{document}

% ...

\includegraphics{mydir/file01.csv_.pdf}
```

... and this seems to work fine, without any changes to the filename argument of `\includegraphics`. Note that `command` argument can be left empty (it's for a system conversion otherwise), and `read-file` is where do we read the size/bounding box information from: since the `.csv_.pdf` is a `.pdf` file proper, with `*` we simply say - read the size from the same file that has matched the declared extension.