# Texmaker generated pdf file not showing the position of cursor

Tags: pdf, texmaker, ubuntu, forward-inverse-search

I am compiling LaTeX files with Texmaker on Ubuntu 12.04 system.

When I run pdflatex and then view the pdf file (internal), it does not show me the exact place where I am editing on Texmaker i.e. the generated pdf file does not show me the position of the cursor.

But some days before it was working fine. I don't know what causes this problem.

I already tried uninstalling and then reinstalling, I did update and upgrade too. But the problem still persists.

Comment: Happy New Year and [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: synchronization between source `TeX` files and the resulting dvi or pdf file is done with `synctex` support. I hope you have added `-synctex=1` option to `pdflatex` command to enable `synctex` and thereby generating `fileName.synctex.gz` file which stores the linkages between source and pdf. `synctex` does not like special characters, follow [best practices for file names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12176/15717). If this does not solve your problem. post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to help others to help you.

Comment: Thanks 'texenthusiast' for your suggestion. The synctex is working fine for me and now I can see the edited place on the pdf file.

Comment: This can also happen if you edit your tex file but do not compile it; then the PDF window might not be able to syncronize with the TeX window of TexMaker...

Answer (score 12):

Synchronization between source TeX files and the resulting dvi or pdf file is done with `synctex` support. You must add the `-synctex=1` option to the `pdflatex` command to enable `synctex` and thereby generating `fileName.synctex.gz` file which stores the linkages between source and pdf. synctex does not like special characters, follow [best practices for file names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12176/15717).

Answer (score 3):

As Martin Schröder wrote:

> synctex does not like special characters, follow best practices for file names.

But this is applicable even for all names of directories, in which the tex file is. I had the same problem. The synctex seemed to stop working. The problem was in a name of some directory containing diacritics in my native language. When this directory was renamed, everything worked as before.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE . I don't see the difference between your answer and the one from Martin Schröder in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Schröder's answer is quite correct. I solved the problem, not only by changing the name of the .tex file but also by changing the names of the folders it was in. The entire path to the .tex file must not contain any special characters.

For example :

**False :** D:\OneDrive - HESSO\HES - SO (Fribourg)\R**é**sum**é**s de cours\D**é**monstrations (B**é**ton et milieux continus)

**Right :** D:\OneDrive - HESSO\HES - SO (Fribourg)\Resumes\Demonstration

I'm not sure if it's just the French accents **éè**, but as soon as I removed them, it worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

This has most likely to do with your version of pdflatex.

Check it by opening up cmd (Windows start -> run -> cmd.exe) and type

`pdflatex --version`

If your version does not correspond to the version on http://miktex.org/, remove the old version of MiKTex from your computer and download and install the newest MikTex version to your computer.