# Texmaker generated pdf file of multi-file latex not showing the position of cursor

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu, viewers, preview

I am compiling LaTeX files with Texmaker on Ubuntu 14.04 system.

When I run pdflatex and then view the `.pdf` file (internal), it does not show me the exact place where I am editing on Texmaker i.e. the generated pdf file does not show me the position of the cursor.

This question was already asked before ([Texmaker generated pdf file not showing the position of cursor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/texmaker-generated-pdf-file-not-showing-the-position-of-cursor)) but the answers don't work in my case.

Probably the reason is that I am using a multi-file latex (each chapter in a separate tex) and I compile a `template.tex` file which has the `\include` command to "call" the separate `chapters*.tex` files.

Comment: Make the main file (the one with preamble) to be the Master Document.

Comment: @ Sigur: I have already tried that, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @LCF, to make sure: are you using the synctex option?

Answer (score 1):

Even though I first did not notice, the comment by Sigur appeared to be the correct answer - thanks for that!

*When making the main file to be the Master Document, one can compile each chapter separately without the need to compile the main file.*

Then, when running pdflatex and viewing the internal .pdf file, it shows me the exact place where I am editing on Texmaker.