# Synchronization is not working

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker, forward-inverse-search

This is the same question as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/texmaker-generated-pdf-file-not-showing-the-position-of-cursor#) but as far as I see, I do have the "synctex=1" command and I have reinstalled both TexMaker and MikTex.
[image]

I checked the synchronization on a new .tex file with minimal packages and a simple name but it still doesn't work, so I would like to know where the problem comes from. The file does compile, I can see the pdf file, it does create the ***.synctex file. And there is no error message.

Comment: I saw that comment in another question, will try it later: "Run the [Miktex] update system both in 'normal' and 'admin' mode"