# “click to jump to the line” is not working!

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search

I use "Texmaker-3.5.2" with "basic-miktex-2.9.4757" on Windows 8.1 on my personal laptop (LenovoZ5070).

I checked Options\Configure Texmaker\Commands. It includes:

LATEX:     latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

PDFLATEX:  pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

XLATEX:    xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

You can see that my system contains "-synctex=1". However “click to jump to the line”  is not working! Please help me.

Comment: Are you running `pdflatex`?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: This can also happen if you edit your tex file but do not compile it; then the PDF window might not be able to syncronize with the TeX window of TexMaker...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem on windows 7 and found a solution from here:
[http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=23400]

Frank in the answer said on that site: *get rid of any spaces or special characters from your file names.*

Comment: I did answer the question - "the site said to get rid of any spaces or special characters from your file names". My answer was not a "link-only" answer. And I don't think a simple solution like this needs an example. (I included the link as an attribute)

Comment: This is not working for me. I am on Windows 7 and I have Texmaker 5.0.2 (compiled with Qt 5.8.0). I Do not have any spaces in the file names (nowhere) and still, I can't jump from the pdf to the editor.

Comment: The answer is here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/texmaker-generated-pdf-file-not-showing-the-position-of-cursor

you just need to add `-synctex=1` to the pdflatex command

Comment: Also use Cmd+Click (or rightclick in the pdf to see options), rather than just click.