# Sublime Text 3, LaTeXing, and R

Tags: r, sublime-text

I have been using Sublime Text 3 in conjunction with the LaTeXing and R-Box packages to write/compile `.Rnw` files. Everything was working fine until I updated to a newer version of R (3.4.3). I have added R 3.4.3 to my environment variables and have changed the setting in R-Box as well to the new directory.

Now, I can write/compile in R-Studio as I had done previously in ST3, but if I try to compile the same document in ST3 I get a fatal error emergency stop.

Any thoughts on what I may have missed?

Thanks! Below is some additional information; not sure if it's what you need. I'm admittedly out of my element. And, sorry if things are not formatted correctly; new here.

Here is error in ST3:

> [Compile ~\Documents\test again\test.rnw]   E:
>   C:\Users\smramsey\Documents\test again\test.tex:0 Emergency stop   1
>   error, 0 warnings, 0 badboxes

And here is what was in the text file that was created:

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.10.29)  8 MAR 2018 17:20
> entering extended mode
>  restricted \write18 enabled.
>  %&-line parsing enabled.
> **"C:/Users/smramsey/Documents/test again/test.tex"
> ! Emergency stop.
> <*> ...ers/smramsey/Documents/test again/test.tex"
>
> *** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
>
>
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>  6 strings out of 492990
>  229 string characters out of 6136333
>  54148 words of memory out of 5000000
>  3663 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
>  3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
>  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>  0i,0n,0p,1b,6s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I may have got it resolved. I had seen on another post that a space in the file name could cause this: [How to resove "job aborted, file error in nonstop mode" error in Texmaker (64-bit)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160532/how-to-resove-job-aborted-file-error-in-nonstop-mode-error-in-texmaker-64-bi).

That didn't apply to me, but, appears it was a space in the folder name. Could have sworn I tried some where this shouldn't have been an issue, maybe something else I changed along the way also played a role. The only other thing I recall doing in the interim was updating the TexLive manager and then all of the packages.

Comment: Are you on current TeXlive? I vaguely remember that this problem was in TeXlive 2019; but with LuaTeX, not pdfTeX ...