# Update failure, failure to compile and now unable to remove

Tags: miktex, installing, windows

I use MiKTeX 2.9 along with LyX in Windows 7.

Last week I downloaded and updated LyX and it worked fine. 
After that I tried to update MiKTeX, but it failed or was not properly completed.

Since then LyX can't compile documents in PDF. Specifically, when I try to compile a document, after several minutes LyX generates a message that reads

> The command pdflatex 'document name' has not yet completed. Do you
>   want to stop it?

Two options are offered, "Stop it" and "Let it run".

When I choose "Let it run", exactly the same message is generated after a while.

When I choose "Stop it", it generates the following message:

> File does not exist:
>   `C:\Users\choix129\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpbuf0\file name.pdf`

So I thought I'd rather uninstall the MiKTeX from the computer and reinstall it completely. Then I went to the control panel and chose MiKTeX 2.9. Then I encounter a message:

> Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Once I click "OK", then I find a message suggesting

> This program might not have uninstalled correctly. If this program
>   didn't uninstall correctly, try uninstalling using settings that are
>   compatible with this version of Windows.

So I click the option "Uninstall using recommended setting" but then it doesn't generate any more feedback.

So I find myself badly stuck. Could any of you please help me out? Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you launch `MiKTeX Options`? If so,  try `Refresh FNDB` and  `update formats` (close LyX first, just in case).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I'm not sure how LyX passes filename information to `pdflatex`, but if you do, in fact, have a space(s) in your file name, that _might_ cause a problem. Refer to [Naming LaTeX files: best practice?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12174/naming-latex-files-best-practice) for more details.

Comment: Bernard, your suggestion works! Now all the problems seem to have been solved and LyX and MikTeX compile documents without any problem. Thanks a lot. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Paul, your suggestion sounds helpful to me. I think I should refer to "Naming the LaTeX files" material you recommend. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Martin for beautifully editing my question. I wonder where I can find information on how to format questions properly.

Comment: @Lachesis Have a look here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx Welcome to TeX.SX!