# What characters cannot be in LyX file name?

Tags: lyx

After wasting a good deal of time, I re-discovered that LyX file names cannot contain apostrophes, otherwise the typesetting doesn't work. I kept getting a "pdflatex.exe has stopped working" error.

Are there any other characters which cause similar problems?

Comment: I would stick to (non-accented Latin) letters, numbers, hyphens and, if you must, underscores. A dot should be used to separate the filename from its extension. Anything else invites trouble.

Comment: I can create and compile LyX files with apostrophes without problem on Ubuntu (and not doing anything special). Can you please post a minimal example and give more details on your OS? If you think you find a bug in LyX, please post a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: Might or might not be duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12174/naming-latex-files-best-practice?noredirect=1&lq=1