# Texmaker: Syncronisation between PDF and TEX file is not working for one project

Tags: texmaker, classicthesis, forward-inverse-search

I using the ClassicThesis template and TeXmaker for a project. Now I have the problem that the syncronisation (synctex, I guess) of the pdf-file an the tex-file is not working. Everything else works, but I need the sync function to make progress properly. I have already used ClassicThesis with the same modifications for my master thesis, where the snycronisation worked fine. For the new project I did not change anything in the configuration file (`classicthesis-config.tex`) but my title, subtitle, etc..

(Just to mention it: The file name of the current projekt is like it is recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12176).)

Has somebody an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: You need to pass the `synctex` option to `pdflatex`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Check that the directories do not contain spaces or eight bits characters. Also, be sure that the combination of directory and file names is not too long. I have sometimes renamed files to four characters, and moved the project to c:\temp for compiling. If synctex then functions, you know that is something with the combination of file and directory names. Sometimes I have followed all the rules, but still the syncing is not functioning.

Comment: Are there any news here?