# Tex File naming convention

Tags: best-practices, external-files

Is it possible to number tex files? I'm avoiding it now but, I would like to order a list of files (chapters in a book) so that each chapter is easy to find. Will this cause a problem? I have in mind:

```
aaa_introduction
001_chapter_one.tex
002_chapter_two.tex
bbb_backmatter.tex
etc.
```

Mike

Comment: You can name your files any way you like. `chapter01.tex`, `chapter02.tex` ... will sort themselves nicely.

Comment: Sure, other than restrictions on spaces (never a good idea) or really funny characters, most filenames will work.  I generate stimulus lists with LaTeX using numbered filenames, which allows me to generate the lists with a loop.

Comment: And related: [allowable filenames for source files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12174/2693).

Comment: I often use `1-whatever.tex` etc. for this purpose. (Mainly for sections of a course.)