# How do I include a path to my image in graphicx?

Tags: graphics, paths

I want to specify `path-to-image\image.png` but for obvious reasons that will not work because `\...` is interpreted as a command.  How do I include a path to my image?  (I'm on Windows 7).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Data Analysis Files\InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count.png}
\end{document}
```

I also tried reversing the slash and using the `grffile` package with the `space` option as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Data Analysis Files/InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15387/specifying-an-absolute-windows-path-for-includegraphics

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Paths and Linux/Windows slash conventions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18913/paths-and-linux-windows-slash-conventions)

Comment: Forgive me, I saw some of those previous threads but I tried a number of permutations of the solutions but couldn't get it to work including reverse the slash, invoke grffile pkg with space option, but no luck still...I would be grateful if someone would suggest an explicit solution...

Comment: The source of problem is the path with spaces, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path/9030#9030

Comment: @ptrcao Put quotes around the name: `"Data Analysis Files/InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count.png"`

Comment: @egreg: Quotes do not help. I have tried several month ago, see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path/9030#9030

Comment: @ptrcao: I reproduced your folder structure and was able to compile your second example (the one with `\usepackage[space]{grffile}`) without getting any errors or warnings, using MiKTeX 2.9 on Win7. Which distribution do you use? Make sure `grffile` is installed and updated.

Comment: @ptrcao: Asking the other way round: What kind of error messages or warnings do you get when compiling the `grffile` example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{\string"Data Analysis Files\string\InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count"}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `"Data Analysis Files\InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count"' not found.

Comment: I work with Ubuntu and it works for me. Sorry. Is the name of the file `Data Analysis Files\InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count`

Comment: This one works for me, too (MiKTeX 2.9 on Win7). `...Count.png"}` doesn't work; `...Count".png}` and `...Count"}` (Marco's) work.

Comment: The path is "Data Analysis Files\"
The filename is "InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count"
Is that what you meant?

Comment: Relative links are allowed right?

Comment: Yes, it finally works - \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{"Data Analysis Files/InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count"} is sufficient apparently, reverse the slash and insert inside inverted commas.  \string works but is not apparently needed.  Thanks Marco :)

Comment: @ptrcao: Great, I'm glad your problem could be helped. A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) in comments as well as in questions and answers. It just makes it much easier to read.

Comment: thx for the tip ;)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that works is to use the short DOS path name. In the DOS prompt window enter `dir /x` to obtain the short names. Use `\detokenize` to get around the tildes `~` in the file names.

```
\includegraphics{\detokenize{DATAAN~1/INTERA~1}}
```

I normaly use a Python script to get needed short names by copying an exsiting path into the script below.

```python
import win32api

#Copy and paste an existing path here
path = r'C:\Users\dnjels\Documents\DE-LaTeX\Temp\Tests\Data Analysis Files\InteractionPlotforTransLog10(X+1)Count.png'

shortpath = win32api.GetShortPathName(path)
shortpath = shortpath.replace('\\','/')

print  shortpath
print  r'\detokenize{' + shortpath + '}'
```

This will give (on my system)

`C:/Users/dnjels/DOCUME~1/DE-LaTeX/Temp/Tests/DATAAN~1/INTERA~1.PNG`

Comment: Thanks Danie, apparently the solution was simpler than I thought but the nobel effort has been recognised with an upvote.  I'm probably not knowledgeable enough to get my head around this yet, but someone else will find it useful, I'm sure :)