# PNG not loading with TeXworks

Tags: graphics

I get this error when trying to load .png file

I import

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\projectfigures} }

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{definitiongraphexample.png}

\end{document}
```

The problem is I get this error

```
! Undefined control sequence.

\reserved@b ->C:\Users 
                       \Daniel \Desktop \projectfigures 
l.423 ...[width=2.5cm]{definitiongraphexample.png}
```

I can't seem to load it. I've tried to load include{path} and that didn't work. So I'm now trying to graphicspath

What am I doing wrong?

`\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicsx}` doesn't get an error and it doesn't say to download it so I don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Use direct and not reverse slashes: `C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/projectfigures`

Comment: egreg I have tried that, but I get this error ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `definitiongraphexample.png' not found.

Comment: Add also a trailing /: `\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/projectfigures/}}`. See also the related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15387/specifying-an-absolute-windows-path-for-includegraphics Finally, remove the `pdftex` option to `graphicx`

Comment: egreg thanks that solved the problem. The image loads now. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

As explained in the related question [Specifying an absolute Windows path for \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15387/specifying-an-absolute-windows-path-for-includegraphics) one has to use "direct" and not "reverse" slashes for specifying paths in Windows.

The TeX programs know how to replace the slashes for going to the required directory; this is because the backslash is interpreted as usual in TeX as prefixing a command name.

Moreover, you should add a trailing slash for the path:

```
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/projectfigures/}}
```

so when the whole string is prepended to the file name you get the correct

```
C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/projectfigures/definitiongraphexample.png
```

Two more tips.

1. Don't specify an extension; `pdflatex` will find the file and this adds to portability:

   ```
   \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{definitiongraphexample}
   ```
2. Don't specify the `pdftex` option to `graphicx`

   ```
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   ```

   is sufficient.