# inserting image on latex

Tags: graphics

I try to insert a graphic but it does not work. I try the following one ;

```
\begin{figure}[!htb] \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5in]{D:\Utilisateurs\e0g411j00nm\Dropbox\images/phasediagram1.eps}
    \caption{Effects of ....}
  \label{fig:SOvsBAU} \end{figure}
```

why it does not work ? All my documents are in the same file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SX! `does not work` is not really helpful. You should give more information

Comment: Have a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15387/specifying-an-absolute-windows-path-for-includegraphics

Comment: It's not necessary to include file extension: `.eps`.

Comment: Your path has a mix of backslash and forward slash characters.  That's probably not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer to my own question. The problem was with the back and forward slashes. When all your files are in the same file, it is not necessary to write the path. You can just put the name of the eps file.

Here it is the right code ;

```
 \begin{figure}
    [!htb]\centering
    \includegraphics[width=5in]{phasediagram1}
    \caption{Effect of ...}
  \label{fig:phase}
  \end{figure}
```