# Is it possible to include files in a custom texstudio template?

Tags: texstudio

I am trying to create a TexStudio template for my University rapports in which I want to include a watermark and a logo for my title page. Is there a way to include these .png files in the template (or perhaps make it so that Texstudio can find the files no matter where the .tex file is located). Naturally, I could copy the files every time to where the .tex is loacted but I'd rather not if it's not necessary.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If the logos are relatively simple you can draw them in the document using Ti*k*Z, PSTricks, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an absolute file path in the template. This way no matter where you use the template (as long as it is on your PC) it uses the same file you can store in a directory somewhere. Explanation on how that works: [Specifying an absolute Windows path for \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15387/specifying-an-absolute-windows-path-for-includegraphics)

(As I could answer my own question in about 10 minutes of googling I feel a bit silly asking it in the first place. Not sure how helpful it is to future users. Should I leave it up or delete it altogether? Not sure what the etiquette of TeX.SX is.)

Comment: If you are happy with your solution accept it, I will leave my answer for others who wish to use their own choice between "user" customised layouts.

Comment: Will do. However, I can only accept my own answer 2 days after I have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the editor with a fresh template or trim your existing down to a basic level, then select Make Template . It will be saved in the config template users directory.

In your template before you save it you can add to the preamble common places for images.

```
\graphicspath{{./}{drive:/your/images/path/}{./subfolder/}{etc}}
```

By default there will not be a thumbnail, however if you take a copy of the default template_report.png and add it into the users folder as the same name as your template it will show as a thumbnail. Using a paint package you can snapshot your own contents to make it more pertinent to your own contents.

[image]