# How do I make pdfLaTeX accept a graphics file with a period in its name?

Tags: graphics, pdftex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\includegraphics: Dots in filename](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/includegraphics-dots-in-filename)

Many of my graphics files have periods in their names. This causes a problem with pdflatex. For example, if I want to include the graphics file `this.or.that.pdf`  I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .or.that.pdf.
```

Is there a way around this other than renaming all my files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{{{this.or.that}.pdf}}` i.e., the file name should be `{this.or.that}.pdf`.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, using [`grffile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grffile):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{clipboard.01}
% \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{clipboard.01.png}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `graphicx` the filetype is defaulted from the extension but for cases like this there is a type key so you can go `type=eps` or `type=bmp` or whatever is needed.