# Why filename with two dot such as "a.b.eps" cannot be compiled by xelatex?

Tags: graphics

I have a figure name "L=10_W=8.00.eps", I put it in the \figure environment by

```
\includegraphics{L=10_W=8.00.eps}
```

compile it with xelatex, but get error:     File ended prematurely

After I renamed it to "L=10_W=8.eps", the error goes away.

Comment: Try adding [`\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}`](http://ctan.org/pkg/grffile).

Comment: latex uses the file extension (by default) to determine the file type and .00.eps is an unknown filetype, see the graphicx package documentation for keys you can use to specify the filetype without  having to parse the filename

Comment: This question was tagged floats but is unrelated to floats (you would see the same wherever you used `\includegraphics`

Comment: @olga.saucedo hm I suppose I should answer there, the question is duplicate but the mechanism built in to graphicx to deal with this isn't mentioned in the answers to the other question.

Comment: as said in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/includegraphics-dots-in-filename

put the filename in {} is a simple solution.

    \includegraphics{{L=10_W=8.00}.eps}

Comment: @Tim It seems to work but by accident (as I can say with some certainty as it's my code:-) the `{}` hide the extension from the scanner but one would have expected them _not_ to be dropped when referring to a file name, just as `\input{{a.b}.tex}` does _not_ work.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me, tell latex it is eps type and the extension to use for the file itself and to find the bounding box

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\includegraphics[width=5cm,ext=.1.eps,type=eps,read=.1.eps]{example}

\end{document}
```

this includes `example.1.eps`  using xelatex.