# Dots in filename, underscores in extension

Tags: input, external-files, naming, underscore

I have the following svg I want to include, that I've nicely converted to a pdf following [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex).

Now I want to include it in my document, however the document's name and path:
`fig/plots/php-src/2013-01/weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes-curves.pdf_tex` are causing me a headache.  How do I escape it so that `\input` understands it???

Comment: So currently you use `\input{fig/plots/php-src/2013-01/weka...pdf_tex}`? I don't get a problem when I just include a file using `\input{this.is.an.external.document.pdf_tex}`...

Comment: Huh.  I was running into issues before with \includegraphics and the dots in the filename, but I just tried it again, and it seems to work...

Comment: Actually, I'm not crazy.  The auto-generated pdf_tex file needed to have braces around the filename, as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/includegraphics-dots-in-filename, I think...

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that I had been using braces around part of the filename with dots, as specified by this question, as if I was using `\includegraphics` [\includegraphics: Dots in filename](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/includegraphics-dots-in-filename)
So like:
`\input{{path/to/file.with.dots}.pdf_tex}`.

As Werner mentioned, just `\input{path/to/file.with.dots.pdf_tex}` works fine.

However, in the autogenerated file in the solution to the question I mention originally, I need to add moustache braces around the filename there (the combination of errors was confusing me), where the pdf is included with `\includegraphics`.