# include graphics with dot in filename: protection with braces does not work

Tags: pdftex, punctuation, includegraphics

I want to include an eps figure whose filename contains more than a dot. As discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/includegraphics-dots-in-filename) one should insert `{ }` in the filename without the extension. However, `pdflatex` still complains that it does not recognize the file type.

Source of a minimal example:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{{test.0}.eps}
\end{document}
```

Using `pdflatex` I get

> ! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics
>   extension: .0.eps.

Using the suggestions of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54653)

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[type=eps,ext=.0.eps,read=.0.eps]{test}
\end{document}
```

remove the error. However, pdflatex produces a pdf with an empty box.

`pdflatex --version` gives

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
```

My `grffile.sty` has

```
Version: 2017/06/30 v1.18
```

Comment: with current releases it should just work without any `{}` (the pdftex version isn't important, the ltex and graphics versions would b. on older releases use the grffile package (which does nothing in current releases so it soesn't hurt to load that anyway)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ```\includegraphics{test.0.eps}``` gives the same error ```Unknown graphics extension: .0.eps```

Comment: then you have an old release but as I say grffile package should make it parse that as extension .eps

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my grffile is from 2017, see updated question

Comment: the version of grffile is irrelevant to the example posted that does not use it, but an up to date texlive 2019 should have `\ProvidesPackage{grffile}%
  [2019/11/11 v2.1 Extended file name support for graphics (legacy)]`

Comment: in any case, since pdflatex can not include eps, it is simpler to convert it to pdf with a command such as `epstopdf test0.eps` and then use the pdf file with `\includegraphics`