# How to include SVG with dots in file name?

Tags: graphics, svg, inkscape

I'm trying to include SVG images with dots/periods in the file name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}

\includesvg[width=\textwidth]{xgb.clf.output/Images/no.missing.data.Deceased.excluded.max_multiples.10zzDeceasedzz0.5zz0zz0.65zz3_ROC.svg}

\end{document}
```

I'm compiling thus:

```
pdflatex -halt-on-error -shell-escape --draftmode tmp.tex
```

this gives a file not found error, which is obviously not working correctly (after conversion with Inkscape):

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `{./svg-inkscape/no.missing.data.Deceased.excl
uded.max_multiples.10zzDeceasedzz0.5zz0zz0.65zz3_ROC_svg-tex}.pdf' not found: u
sing draft setting.
```

I've tried

```
\includesvg[width=\textwidth]{{xgb.clf.output/Images/no.missing.data.Deceased.excluded.max_multiples.10zzDeceasedzz0.5zz0zz0.65zz3_ROC}.svg}
```

as suggested by

[\includegraphics: Dots in filename](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10574/includegraphics-dots-in-filename) & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344066/allowing-includegraphics-in-latex-to-include-files-with-arbitrary-filenames to no avail, because `\includesvg` seems to work differently than `\includegraphics`

I've also tried removing the `svg` extension, but the error persists.

Using `grffile` also fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{document}

\includesvg[width=\textwidth]{xgb.clf.output/Images/no.missing.data.Deceased.excluded.max_multiples.10zzDeceasedzz0.5zz0zz0.65zz3_ROC.svg}

\end{document}
```

How can I include SVG with dots in the filename?

Comment: `\usepackage{grffile}`

Comment: @HenriMenke could you show exactly how that would work? adding the `grffile` package, and 1) typing in real file name, 2) typing in with `{}` around file/directory, still produces the same error :(

Comment: You only need to load the package. No other shenanigans are needed after that.

Comment: @HenriMenke I've added how I added the file, and still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `inkscapename=outFilename` seems tho solve the problem for me.

See [svg package documentation](https://ctan.net/graphics/svg/doc/svg.pdf) in Chapter B.1.3. Setting output folder and file.

```
\includesvg[width=\textwidth,inkscapename=outFilename]{...}
```

Comment: I should add that `outFilename` should be unique for every call to `includesvg`

Comment: I assume that otherwise it will be overwritten in the folder generated by inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

Please update package `svg` as this issue (https://github.com/mrpiggi/svg/issues/27) was resolved some time ago and I can't replicate your problem with the current version `2020/11/26 v2.02k`